# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' in spyder

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I tried to use torch in spyder but I got error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'` so I tried use pip module not in cmd but in spyder itself following

```
import pip
pip.main(["install","torch"])
```

but got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'` and I know I had successfully used it in spyder before but recent automatic spyder updates probably have caused this error so I tried to install pip in my all python environments in cmd with `cd {environment_path}`but the pip was installed there. I also used `python -m ensurepip` in all environments but I still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`.

Comment: facing the same issue. Not sure why, I could see that PyCharm has the module installed in the module list under settings. But when I am importing it, PyCharm do not give any suggestion. However, I am facing the error with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XmlXdiff'

Comment: @user3521180 I updated torch in base root environment and the problem got solved and Also specified the environment in spyder, so you do it in pycharm

Comment: @FarhangAmaji, are you using our Windows or macOS installer?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba HI Im using windows and not with installer. thanx for your spyder project, best ide ever as I know but it's got really slow in 5(5.0.2 was a little bit better but when its on for long time again gets slower), another thing I don't want to install kite, so if it is possible improve your completions yourselves and another point is that I thing I downgraded 5.0.1 to 4.5 but it upgraded itself if Im not mistaken. another thing with installing newer versions it keeps previous one. and anaconda navigator don't track your sub versions 5.0.x .

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I found out after reseting spyder it happens for sure. I don't know maybe other things also cause this. changing different python interpreters (environments) also is no help!! this time I recently reinstalled spyder 5.0.3 by windows installer.

Comment: and I again reinstalled it with windows installer and solved the problem.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba HI carlos , I still have this problem, recently I uninstalled 5.0.5 with an windows unistaller (IObit uninstaller) and deleted the the anaconda spyder (5.0.0) from navigator and installed the 5.1.1 but it does not recognize 'pip' and many other packages. also there is not spyder reset so I reseted it within spyder reset to factory defaults and reinstalled it and it was no help.

Comment: I installed them with windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

seems the problem is caused by reseting spyder(maybe there other causes) changing different python interpreters (environments) also is no help!! and installing or reinstalling with windows installer solved problem for me.

update: after restarting again many modules like 'pip', 'torch' and 'keyboard' are not recognized and reinstalling is no answer(no difference between installing for 'this user' or 'all users').