# No module named 'nets'

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm running an object detection code and still getting this error"

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets'

Do you have any suggestions to resolve it?

Comment: I assume you haven't installed it or imported it. Show your code please.

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed the module. It's not part of the Python standard library so Python won't be able to find it until you install it.

Comment: from nets import inception_resnet_v2

Comment: This is the line that I'm getting the error from

Comment: Also, I'm running the code in a virtual environment in Spyder

Answer (score 0):

first of all try this to make sure that you have installed the following package in your environment:

```
import pip
pip.main(["install","nets"])
```

then if you get errors it maybe the bug sometimes you may face and check my question [module dectection in spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67564147/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pip-in-spyder) which says reinstalling with spyder os installer sometimes works.